# canvas.getMatrix() is deprecated

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to create PDF using canvas.

```
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(heightPx, widthPx, bimType);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    AffineTransform form = new AffineTransform(canvas.getMatrix());
```

But Now I am getting canvas.getMatrix() is deprecated. I come to know that need to use View.getMatrix(). But I am not able to get the view from bitmap. Any one can give idea for this please?

Answer (score 0):

the reason why The method is deprecated may be that when enabled hardware acceleration, it doesn't respond. you can see this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36938987)

As for using the bitmap to create the pdf,  you can use this library: `iText`

```
    //add this library
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.12'

    // use the following code to create
    //where the pdf locate
    File file = new File("iText_Image_Example.pdf");
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(file);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    //get the source image
    ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create("logo.png");
    Image pdfImg = new Image(imageData);
    
    document.add(pdfImg);
    document.close();
```

you also can use Transformation, not directly use `getMatrix`. To generate PDf, you can use [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html).

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(100, 100, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

// Draw the bitmap onto the page
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
document.finishPage(page);
```